# Oracle : Execute Stored Procedure with table type input variable

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

When I tried to debug an existing app, I found 1 method which is execute a stored procedure showing an error. I want to execute the Stored Procedure on my Oracle SQLDeveloper, given procedure :

```
type numTableType is table of NUMBER index by binary_integer;

PROCEDURE up_correction_status(p_exp_check_id IN numTableType, p_status_id NUMBER, p_user_id NUMBER, p_return OUT NUMBER);
```

but, how to declare value of `numTableType` ?

I tried to :

```
var p_return NUMBER;
execute "PKG_PDM_DASHBOARD".up_approved_corr_status(1, 2, 11, :p_return);
print p_return;
```

Found this error :

> Error starting at line 2 in command:
>   execute "PKG_PDM_DASHBOARD".up_approved_corr_status(1, 2, 11, :p_return)
>   Error report:
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UP_APPROVED_CORR_STATUS'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

just want to execute it and get return value

Comment: where is the body of the procedure?

Comment: Sorry, Added some information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `type` usage is possible within a package. Outside a package you have to `create type`.

For execution of procedures with such complex type parameters use a pl/sql anonymous block.
Execution template:

```
declare
  X tableType;
begin
  X(1) := 1;
  P(X);
end;
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to execute that kind of procedure, pls